# Expectation Maximization implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, mixed-models, expectation-maximization

I am not sure as to what I am doing wrong with this code. I am trying to implement the expectation maximization algorithm(pseudo code screenshot below) and I think I am not minimizing the Beta correctly. Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

This is the link to the pseudocode here >
[EM Algo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooXZ7.png)

Below is the code I have wrote to duplicate the pseudocode

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")


#b_1 = np.random.randn(5,1)
#b_2 = np.random.randn(5,1)
b_1 = np.array([1,1,2,2,2])
b_2 = np.array([2,2,1,1,3])
iteration = 500
data_y = np.random.random_integers(500, size=(300, 1))
data_x = np.random.random_integers(500, size=(300, 5))


def em(b_1,b_2,iteration, data_y, data_x):
    for t in range(1, iteration+1):
        J_1=[]
        J_2=[]
        for i in range(len(data_y)):
            if abs(data_y[i]-(np.dot(data_x[i],b_1))) < abs(data_y[i]-(np.dot(data_x[i],b_2))):
                J_1.append(i)
            else:
                J_2.append(i)
        b_1 = np.argmin((np.sum(J_1[data_y] - (J_1[data_x])*b_1)**2)**.5)
        b_2 = np.argmin((np.sum(J_2[data_y] - (J_2[data_x])*b_2)**2)**.5)

    return b_1, b_2
```

the specific question is how can I minimize the betas in a way that they converge with the true betas i initially set in those 500 iterations.

```
b_1 = np.argmin((np.sum(J_1[data_y] - (J_1[data_x])*b_1)**2)**.5) 
b_2 = np.argmin((np.sum(J_2[data_y] - (J_2[data_x])*b_2)**2)**.5)
```

I get this error on the lines above

```
only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Ultimately I want to be able to find a radius around the true betas of how far off the initial guess of the Betas can be from the true Betas where it will still converge to the true betas in 500 iterations

Comment: What is your specific question? Does this program fail with an error? Does it give unexpected results? These are important clues to help us figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: the specific question is how can I minimize the betas in a way that they converge with the true betas i initially set in those 500 iterations.

Comment: b_1 = np.argmin((np.sum(J_1[data_y] - (J_1[data_x])*b_1)**2)**.5)
b_2 = np.argmin((np.sum(J_2[data_y] - (J_2[data_x])*b_2)**2)**.5)

I get this error on these lines:
only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: Please edit your question to add these clarifications. It's impossible to read in the comments. Just click the **edit** button above the comments.

Comment: okay will do, sorry about that